# Странность с FTP-соединением в некоторых ОС из ПО на Delphi

Tags: delphi, ftp, delphi-xe

Разработано ПО, используется IdFTP1.Connected, для соединения с FTP-Сервером.
Соединение с авторизацией по логин и паролю.
Но вот беда, что в некоторых ОС, чаще это (Win-7) происходит ошибка "Server cannot accept argument".
Пока что клиентов 5-6, но у 2-х уже такая вот ошибка.
Заметил ещё одну странность. Если добавлять из интерфейса Windows (правая кнопка в окне "мой ПК"), то при завершении элемент система пишет, "при подключении к FTP у вас будет запрошен пароль", но запрос пароля не выдаётся, а открывается сразу FTP с сообщением, что у вас нет доступа к данному ресурсу. (Хотя такое на других, у кого работает такой метод не тестировал).
P.S. ПО моё, FTP-сервер тоже мой, так что ошибки в связках логин-пароль, быть не может.
Может кто уже встречал такое?

### (FireWall отключен)

**UPD:**
В коде:
Делаю `IdFTP1.Connect;` и далее по коду `IdFTP1.Put(file_pathname_source, file_pathname_target, false); IdFTP1.Disconnect;`. Другого ни чего лишнего вроде нет.
Может наоборот чего-то недостаёт?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подключаетесь в пассивном режиме (`IdFTP1.Passive:= True`)?

Comment: @zed, такой параметр вообще не использую. Делаю `IdFTP1.Connect;` и там по коду `IdFTP1.Put(file_pathname_source, file_pathname_target, false);` и всё.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Заработало!